# Is there a name for the set of Monads that wrap at most one value?

Tags: haskell, monads

As the title says, I'm looking for the name of the set of Monads that wrap at most one value (i.e. monads that call their binding operation at most once). This set includes monads like `Maybe` and `Either`, but not `List`. Does this set have a formal name?

(EDIT: removed `IO` from the list, based on the comments)

Comment: I don't think you can in any meaningful way claim “IO wraps at most one value”.

Comment: I think the IO monad is a bit a tricky one here, since "implicitly" it wraps over the state of the entire world (`IO`, theoretically speaking, stores the state and content of all files, network, devices,...)

Comment: I don't know that they're an important enough concept that anyone thought of naming them. (Might be interesting to try to figure out how to characterise them formally though...)

Comment: As a container, though, `IO a` "wraps" exactly one value of type `a`. Just like `State` isn't a monad, but `State a` is (for some given type `a`). Maybe an affine monad, by analogy with affine types (an object can be used at most once).?

Comment: @chepner `State` is a better example since it can properly be analysed. I'd say `State Bool` wraps exactly two values, `State Int` wraps 2⁶⁴ values, etc.. Then `IO ~ State RealWorld` wraps quite a lot of values...

Comment: But the "state" type isn't relevant to what the OP is asking as I understand. A `Maybe b` value can contain at most one value of type `b`, while `[b]` wraps an arbitrary number of values of type `b`. Likewise, `IO b` wraps exactly one value of type `b`, because the fake `RealWorld` value stored as state doesn't affect any function you would bind the `IO` value to.

Comment: I think this can be formalized as something like this: Monads for which in the expression `x >>= f`, `f` is called at most once.  I still don't know a name for it.

Comment: Well, perhaps you're just looking for _monads isomorphic to `ErrorT e (Writer w)`_.

Comment: @leftroundaboit it would at least be `State` instead of `Writer`. I'm not sure if there are more things.

Comment: @Carl I've abused the term "linear" before, in the sense of linear logic at the type level. The type signature `m a` must use `a` at most once, in the same way that `x >>= f` uses `f` at most once. The reason it's abuse is it would be "linear" if it must use it exactly once.

Comment: @Cirdec "affine" is the word for "used at least once." [See this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substructural_type_system)

Comment: @HTNW: Not quite: *relevant* is “at least once” (no weakening/drop); *affine* is “at most once” (no contraction/copy), and *linear* is “exactly once” (no copy or drop).

Comment: @JonPurdy Whoops, typo. Anyway, I think that's the word we're after.

Comment: It seems that "affine monad" is actually a term used in literature, but unfortunately I'm not nearly familiar enough with category theorem to understand if that is what I meant. They seem to be introduced in the paper "Bilinearity and cartesian closed monads." from "A. Knock" (theorem 2.1).